# ListView Auto Height Based On Items

Tags: android, listview

```
    populateListView();

private void populateListView() {

    List<String> arrEventIDNames = dbHeplper.getALLNames(name);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_layout, R.id.MyTextViewl, populateNames); 

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.finalListView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL05"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

     >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/finalListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Given the above code, how can I set the ListView so that it sets the height automatically based on the number of items (names in my case), so if there is only 1 name it will show the 1 name but if there are 10 names it will show all 10 names without scrolling?

Comment: Do you want the height of the listview to `wrap` it's content's or do you want the contents of the listview to be "squeezed" in order for the listview to have a height equal to the screen so the user will not need to scroll down?

Comment: To wrap, I have tried that option but it doesn't work. If I set the height manually to include 10 items that works great but if the listview has only 1 item then the space for the 9 items remain, so basically the listview (or LinearLayout PARENT) should set it's height according to the listview items, like it does when you use a listview on its own and not inside other layouts

Comment: Let the LinearLayout have a `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and the ListView inside it `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and tell me if it suits your needs.

Comment: Tried that doesn't work, I tried almost everything on the XML side, perhaps taking the JAVA approach would do?

Comment: Doing it from java will give you a better control of the situation but still, what you want to do seems pretty simple and achievable from the XML side. Why didn't it work? What was wrong?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have mentioned that the ListView is inside a ScrollView and yes I know this is bad practice however I would like to still do it

Answer (score 1):

Can you believe I found this as the solution:

Got rid of ListView and replaced it with LinearLayout.

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL05);

        final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
        rowTextView.setText(arrEventIDNames);
        linearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your comment is that your ListView is contained in a ScrollView. Try this for your ListView layout:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

For reference, [android:scrollbars](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars).

Your method is good for few rows of data. You could design the layout with a TextView inside a ScrollView, and perhaps achieve the same thing. And then, you don't require an Adapter.